# Connecting one message flow to another message flow

Tags: spring-integration

I have two flows, both have gateways. One of the flow has outbound gateway to webservice. The second flow should connect to first one. Problem is that I dont know how to do it correctly.

Comment: Improve your question writing skill. Put some related code and error occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your provider is up and running, in the consumer side, What you need is a web service inbound gateway

Bare minimum example (assuming you have imported ws namespace):

```
<ws:inbound-gateway id="myInbound" request-channel="myRequestChannel"/>
```

You will also need to configure your web.xml file, so that incomming SI specific requests are handled by MessageDispatcherServlet.

For application layer abstraction, I will also add a generic gateway listening to the same channel.